# Alt key causes form to redraw

Tags: c#, winforms, repaint

I've come across a problem that I'm hoping one of you fine thinkers can overcome...

For some reason, once I have loaded up my Windows Form, if the user presses the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, the form redraws causing a flash.

This only happens the first time, so any subsequent presses of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key do nothing.

I don't have any menu strips or events that handle the key press, so I can only assume it's either a setting I haven't set, or one that I have unknowingly set.

FYI, the form does the following in the constructor

```
DoubleBuffered = true;
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | 
         ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

This is because I have a number of Panels and Labels that also do the same to implement transparency.

Fingers crossed, one of you will know why ;)

Comment: Well, pressing Alt will put focus on the system menu. It may be entirely possible that that also causes a WM_PAINT message.

Comment: @Joey: I assumed that were to be the case, do you know of a way of preventing this? Thanks ;)

Comment: I haven't seen this behavior on default forms and buttons leading me to suspect a custom control.

Can you try and remove half of the controls on screen to see if the redraw still occurs?. Remove the other half and simply binary search which control is causing the flicker.

Comment: @CodingBarfield: Thanks, your right, I do have a number of custom controls but these are only to allow me to implement transparency and double buffering. It seems related to controls that have the image/background image property populated. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Paste this code into your form:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        // Suppress the WM_UPDATEUISTATE message
        if (m.Msg == 0x128) return;
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

It worked well to suppress the paint when I tried it.  The focus cue handling in Windows is fairly bizarre, do test thoroughly to ensure this doesn't have unexpected side-effects.

Comment: Thank you Hans! I've just based that into my Form base class and straight away it's improved the situation. I'll have a further fiddle but so far it's looking extremely promising!! Thank you again!